# How to bind color to textbox background wpf

Tags: wpf, binding, colors, background

Hi
I have a problem with seting a textbox background color using bindings.
I use this code

```
<TextBlock Width="Auto" Height="Auto"
                                   Text="{Binding ConnectionType}"
                                   Canvas.Left="{Binding LabelPosition.X}"
                                   Canvas.Top="{Binding LabelPosition.Y}" Background="{Binding ParentCanvasColor}">

                          <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="5" Y="5"/>
                          </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                        </TextBlock>
```

ParentCanvasColoris property which is in my class called connection. This property looks like that

```
 public Color ParentCanvasColor
    {
        get
        {
            if (parentCanvas != null && parentCanvas is DesignerCanvasNetDiag)
            {
                return Colors.Red;
            }
            return Colors.Transparent;
        }
    }
```

Of course I added object of class Connection to datacontext of textBlock

Answer (score 6):

bind `SolidColorBrush` instead of `Color` like following.

```
    public SolidColorBrush ParentCanvasColor
    {
        get
        {
            if (parentCanvas != null && parentCanvas is DesignerCanvasNetDiag)
            {
                return  new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            }
            return  new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        }
    }
```